# Remix build issue: catch Boundary ||= error Boundaries.Remix Root Default Catch Boundary

Tags: node.js, npm, remix.run

I'm getting this error `catch Boundary ||= error Boundaries.Remix Root Default Catch Boundary;` when I'm to run the `npm run start` command.

I've tried to re-create the project, but I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I've posted this question for whoever might search for something along these lines. The issue was that I haven't changed the node version before creating the remix project, I had node v.14.16.

Make sure that you're using the node version as per the spec and then create, build and start the project.